# JAVA - Encrypt a text with windows username in AES 128

Tags: java, aes, decode, encode

I would like to use Windows username like a key to crypt and decrypt a text.

But when i try, the key is too short :
Invalid AES key length: 7 bytes

I must encode the key before use ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try padding the key?

Answer (score 5):

Technically - the key needs to be 128 bit long (or 192 or 256 bits). The easiest way is using padding (append some constant values to extend to the required length).

This approach is **HIGHLY INSECURE**, you could consider this approach as encoding, not encryption.

Proper encryption would need

- having the key **secret**. Indeed this is very difficult to achieve if the code/configuration resides on the user's workstation, but using the username sounds as a VERY bad idea from the security perspective
- Salt the key. Create an encryption key from a password using random salt and a hash function (e.g. PBKDF2).

Comment: In addition to using a strong KDF, use the proper number of iterations (aka "cost factor") to mitigate brute force attacks on the derived key -- PBKDF2 is a good choice, but needs somewhere between 10k - 100k iterations for common web application threat models as of Dec 2016 ([commodity hardware systems can crack about 68 billion SHA-1 hashes per second](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/a83d38f412b4737e99bbef804a270c40)). You should tune your KDF to be performant on the hosting system while still introducing delay for attackers.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.
You are right, it'sp probably encoding and not encryption.

But the goal is to crypt and decrypt message and settings from an application.

I will search padding the key.

Comment: Thanks, i will try.
I just need encrypt text from a file to use with a famous software.
And i know the key, but i have not success with encryption...